# Prevent from unauthenticated user to access page ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.Net MVC web application any unauthenticated and anonymous user can type a URL ( for example localhost:16621/Controller/Index/1 ) and access that page. How can I prevent from this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, use the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). But you'll probably need a user system that uses a database or authenticates against Google/Facebook using Oauth.

Comment: While I agree with the answer, I didn't get the reason behind using google/facebook (oauth) esp when it is a localhost. Note that there is nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: @shahkalpesh If you can get over the privacy stuff, using Google/Facebook/[put other Oauth provider here] they can remove a lot of the overhead with user management since the end user won't have yet another account on a website. Also you don't have to roll your own login/logout system, change password, confirm email address, password hashing, etc. Working on localhost is hard to do with oauth providers but you need to start somewhere. And it only works in semi-public sites that don't need to restrict access to known people.

Comment: got it. It is just that the oauth thing might not be what OP is looking for. Thanks for the explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Authorize] attribute.

You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).